# Deno cotton 'must have type'

Tags: deno

I'm following a course on Deno and Angular but I am stuck.  I have even downloaded the final code supplied by the person who created the course and get the same type of error.

When I try and run this commmand: deno run --allow-net --unstable app.ts

I keep getting this error message:

> Check file:///?:/????/deno-admin-main/app.ts
> error: Uncaught Error: Column 'role_id' must have a type!
> throw new Error(`Column '${propertyKey}' must have a type!`);
>
> ^
> at https://deno.land/x/cotton@v0.7.5/src/model.ts:76:13
> at DecorateProperty ([https://deno.land/x/cotton@v0.7.5/src/utils>/reflect.ts:1431:27](https://deno.land/x/cotton@v0.7.5/src/utils%3E/reflect.ts:1431:27))
> at Reflect.decorate (https://deno.land/x/cotton@v0.7.5/src/utils/reflect.ts:858:16)
> at __decorate (file:///?:/????/deno-admin-main/src/models/role-permission.ts:3:92)
> at file:///?:/????/deno-admin-main/src/models/role-permission.ts:9:5

// role-permission

```
import {Model, Primary, Column} from "https://deno.land/x/cotton@v0.7.5/mod.ts";

@Model('role_permissions')
export class RolePermission {
    @Primary()
    id!: number;

    @Column()
    role_id!: number;

    @Column()
    permission_id!: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a typo.   I did not add "app.ts" to the file scripts.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://deno.land/x/denon@2.4.7/schema.json",
  "scripts": {
    "start": {
      "cmd": "deno run app.ts",
      "desc": "run my app.ts file",
      "allow": [ 
        "net"
      ] ,
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json"  
    }
  },
  "watcher": {
    "match": [
      "app.ts",
      "src/**/*.ts"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to their [docs](https://rahmanfadhil.github.io/cotton/guide/model.html#typescript-configuration) the use of this `cotton` feature requires a custom `tsconfig.json` to be included when running the program:

> Keep in mind that this feature requires a custom TypeScript configuration to tell Deno that we want to use TypeScript decorators (opens new window), which is currently still an experimental feature.

```json
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  }
}
```

```
deno run --unstable --config ./tsconfig.json app.ts
```

Comment: Thanks but I have that in already i.e. the tsconfig.json.  I am following a Udemy course and will continue with it.  I have found with many courses an issue is corrected/vanishes later on.